# ¿Cómo importar xls en tablas mysql y comparar valores?

Tags: php, mysql, xls

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. Tengo dos ficheros xls con datos muy similares, que debo cargar en tablas y comparar. En mysql tengo una tabla por cada fichero con la misma estructura. La parte de leer los ficherto sxls e insertar los datos en las tablas, lo tengo funcionando. El tema es el siguiente: cada fichero, tiene una columna que identifica los registros conicidentes en cada excel, y otra columna en la que debo buscar coincidencias o diferencias.
Por ejemplo:
las columnas ID y VALOR existen en cada excel y están importadas a la tabla de cada uno de ellos.
la columna ID, puede tener 1 o varias filas en el excel1 y una coincidencia o varias en el excel2:
Excel1: tiene 3 filas (registros en la tabla) con el mismo ID. La suma de sus datos de VALOR debo compararla con los coincidentes de Excel2:

```
ID=1234 VALOR 100
ID=1234 VALOR 200
ID = 1234 VALOR 50
```

Excel 2:
ID 1234 VALOR 350
En este caso, coinciden, perfecto, me debe decir que coinciden y mostrarlo. Si no coinciden, me lo debe mostrar también.

Espero haberme explicado bien. gracias anticipadas.

---

El index.php de ejemplo que estoy probando:

```
<?php require_once("header.php");
require_once("connect.php");
?>
<!-- FORMULARIO -->
<div class="container">
<h2>Importar excel a MySQL</h2>
<form name="importa" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Seleccionar archivo" name="excel">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="btn btn-default btn-file" type='submit' name='enviar'  value="Importar"  />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="upload" name="action" />
  <input type="hidden" value="usuarios" name="mod">
  <input type="hidden" value="masiva" name="acc">
</form>

<!-- CARGA Y PROCESAMIENTO-->
<?php 
extract($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$action=$_POST['action'];
}

if (isset($action)== "upload"){
//cargamos el fichero
$archivo = $_FILES['excel']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['excel']['type'];
$destino = "cop_".$archivo;//Le agregamos un prefijo para identificarlo el archivo cargado
if (copy($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'],$destino)) echo "Archivo Cargado Con Éxito";
else echo "Error Al Cargar el Archivo";
        
if (file_exists ("cop_".$archivo)){ 
/** Llamamos las clases necesarias PHPEcel */
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');                  
// Cargando la hoja de excel
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("cop_".$archivo);
$objFecha = new PHPExcel_Shared_Date();       
// Asignamon la hoja de excel activa
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$columnas = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
$filas = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();


for ($i=2;$i<=$filas;$i++){
                        $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['nombres'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                        $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['apellidos'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                        $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['genero']= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                        $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['carrera']= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                        $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['edad'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                        $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['email'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
                        $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['activo'] = 1;
                    }       
                    $errores=0;


foreach($_DATOS_EXCEL as $campo => $valor){
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO excel  (nombres,apellidos,genero,carrera,edad,email,activo)  VALUES ('";
                        foreach ($valor as $campo2 => $valor2){
                            $campo2 == "activo" ? $sql.= $valor2."');" : $sql.= $valor2."','";
                        }

                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                        if (!$result){ echo "Error al insertar registro ".$campo;$errores+=1;}
                    }   
                    
echo "<hr> <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <div class='form-group'>";
          echo "<strong><center>ARCHIVO IMPORTADO CON EXITO, EN TOTAL $campo REGISTROS Y $errores ERRORES</center></strong>";
echo "</div>
</div>  ";
                            
                    unlink($destino);
                    
                }
                    
                else{
                    echo "Primero debes cargar el archivo con extencion .xlsx";
                }
            }
        ?>
<?php 
            if (isset($action)) {
$filas = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
                }
            if (isset($filas)) {
$columnas = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
                }
            if (isset($filas)) {
$filas = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
                }

//echo 'getHighestColumn() =  [' . $columnas . ']<br/>';
//echo 'getHighestRow() =  [' . $filas . ']<br/>';
if (isset($action)== "upload"){
echo '<table border="1" class="table">';
    echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>'; 
            echo '<th>Nombres</th>'; 
            echo '<th>Apellidos</th>';
                echo '<th>Genero</th>';
                echo '<th>Edad</th>';
                echo '<th>Carrera</th>';
                echo '<th>E-Mail</th>';

            echo '</tr> ';
        echo '</thead> ';
        echo '<tbody> ';

$count=0;
foreach ($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $count++;
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        if (!is_null($cell)) {
            $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            echo '<td>';
            echo $value . ' ';
            echo '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
  echo '</tbody>';
  echo '</table>';
}
 echo '</div>';
include ("footer.php");
?>
```

Con este empiezo las pruebas. Luego, otro php llamado listar.php:

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');
$ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `excel`";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $ReadSql);
include("header.php");
?>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
    <h2>Mantenimiento de registros insertados con PHP Excel</h2>
        <table class="table"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>#</th> 
                <th>Nombres</th> 
                <th>Apellidos</th> 
                <th>E-Mail</th> 
                <th>Genero</th> 
                <th>Edad</th> 
                <th>Carrera</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <?php 
        $i=0;
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){$i++;
        ?>
            <tr> 
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></th> 
                <td><?php echo $r['nombres']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $r['apellidos']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $r['genero']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $r['edad']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $r['carrera']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $r['email']; ?></td> 

    
            </tr> 
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody> 
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

  


<?php include ("footer.php"); ?>
```

Esto es lo que he probado, y me sirve para cargar los dos excel, cada uno a su tabla. Es lo qu ellevo hasta ahora para probar. A partir de aquí, es donde no sé por donde continuar o como buscar info, pues ya tendría las dos tablas cargadas, y debería empezar con la comparación de registros de ambas.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentando y qué problema concreto tienes en base a eso? Hace falta un punto de partida para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano. Lo primero es que estoy empezando con PHP, y voy a base de manuales, tutos, ejemplos, etc. Hasta ahora, he conseguido montar lo sphp necesario spara leer los excel y cargar los datos en tablas y listarlos. A partir de aqui, no sé como plantearme ni como empezar a codificar el comparar los valores del ejemplo. Se hacer las querys para comparar, pero a nivel de php no sé como seguir para leer los datos, compararlos ya totalizados y devolver los coincidentes y faltantes en ambas tablas para generar otro excel con ellos. Mil gracias

Comment: Te entiendo. El problema es que, para empezar, hay varios tipos de bases de datos, luego, desde PHP hay varias APIs para conectarse a la base de datos, y de PHP mismo hay varias versiones de programa y entre cada cosa hay elementos determinantes. A eso me refiero por punto de partida. Debes mostrar qué código tienes, indicando las herramientas con las que estás trabajando y nosotros te ayudaremos en base a eso. Según lo que explicas, no esperes que se resuelva todo en una sola pregunta. Stackoverflow no es una agencia de asesoría, sino un sitio para responder a problemas puntuales ...

Comment: ... Lo digo porque lo que planteas podría ser demasiado amplio, por lo que te recomiendo que vayas por parte. No hay problema si necesitas abrir varias preguntas, aquí siempre habrá alguien que te ayude y mientras más claro seas mejor. Pero siempre, siempre, debes mostrar lo que llevas hecho, aunque sea un código en una etapa muy inmadura. Partiendo de eso, te diremos, *es mejor hacer esto así o asá*... pero sin punto de partida no podemos decirte, *usa tal herramienta, usa tal otra* porque no es la finalidad del sitio y porque no conocemos tu contexto.

Comment: Perdón, como digo estoy empezando a trompicones con ejemplos y tutoriales. Uso PHp 7.4 con base de datos mysql. Trabajo directamente contra un servidor donde en un dominio, voy subiendo lo sphp y probando. Hasta ahora, tengo dos ficheros, uno para la carga y lectura del excel en la tabla d emysql y otro para leerlo y mostrarlo en una tabla:

Comment: El área de abajo es para respuestas. Si quieres agregar cosas nuevas a la pregunta pulsa en [edit] y agrega el contenido nuevo. Pero con respecto a tu pregunta estamos en el mismo punto. Debes indicar lo que has hecho/investigado con respecto al problema que quieres resolver. Por ejemplo, si es para normalizar los datos (al menos es lo que parece), puedes hacerlo directamente en la base de datos. Si es para mantener los datos así entonces sí tendría sentido escribir código PHP para ello. Es otra duda que no queda clara en tu pregunta.

Comment: La idea es hacer una especie de pequeña aplicación que permita cargar los excel, y a través de un menú llamar a las opciones de comparar valores, listar idénticos, diferentes, etc. Más que normalizar sería tener un histórico de datos, e ir comprobando coincidencias y diferencias. Sobre todo porque hay registros que se repiten con valores que se deben sumar y comparar con la otra tabla.

Comment: Entiendo, pero en una pregunta no se puede resolver la lógica completa de una aplicación. Entonces delimita el problema. **¿Cuál es la dificultad concreta que tienes en este punto de tu programa, qué has investigado, qué has intentado en base a lo investigado y qué problemas o errores tienes y en qué parte del código?** Por ejemplo, tu pregunta abarca áreas tanto de PHP como de SQL. ¿El problema es que no sabes como escribir las consultas? ¿Es con el código PHP? ¿Qué problema exactamente? Volvemos a lo mismo, tu pregunta es demasiado genérica tal y como está planteada ahora.

Comment: Sobre todo es con el PHP, pues las consultas en SQL sé como plantearlas, pero no acabo de ver como llevar la lógica de lo que pretendo al código. Voy a preparar datos mas reales y los pondré aquí para explicarme mejor. Mil gracias por contestar.